# Bitcoin script example

Tags: transactions, protocol, address, script

Is there some good example on how to process a basic tx's scriptsig and get the recipient's address from the raw transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the output there is a field "scriptPubKey" that for a standard transaction looks like this:

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

The hex number is what you get the address from; this is the result of step #3 in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses. To get the address continue the process in that example. (Though, arguably the hardest part is calculating [Base58Check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding), for which an example is not given.)

Also relevant is https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Standard_Transaction_to_Bitcoin_address.

Comment: Hmm, nothing like using the wiki entry I wrote against me ;) (the first one). And the base 58 is not much of a problem, already programmed that awhile ago.

Comment: Has the Script been changed since the Genesis Block? I am having some problems figuring out how to process this scriptPubKey from that block: 4104678AFDB0FE5548271967F1A67130B7105CD6A828E03909A67962E0EA1F61DEB649F6BC3F4CEF38C4F35504E51EC112DE5C384DF7BA0B8D578A4C702B6BF11D5FAC

Comment: This transaction uses the https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Standard_Generation_.2F_transaction_to_IP_address type. In it you have the public key itself before any hashing (step #1). The public key in the genesis block is 04678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5f, I'm not sure where you got this value from.

Comment: It's the same public key, but with opcodes added on both sides - push 0x41 bytes on the left and checksig on the right. So it is a raw scriptpubkey dump from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block