# What are the hashes in Unspent outputs?

Tags: hash, raw-data, output, endianness

I am a newbie to Bitcoin.
Looking at

```
curl https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1Cdid9KFAaatwczBwBttQcwXYCpvK8h7FK
```

I guess that the script is the owner's address.I am not sure about this.

```
"unspent_outputs":[

        {
            "tx_hash":"f2c245c38672a5d8fba5a5caa44dcef277a52e916a0603272f91286f2b052706",
            "tx_hash_big_endian":"0627052b6f28912f2703066a912ea577f2ce4da4caa5a5fbd8a57286c345c2f2",
            "tx_index":47854970,
            "tx_output_n": 1,
            "script":"76a9147f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a888ac",
            "value": 8450000,
            "value_hex": "0080efd0",
            "confirmations":258278
        },
```

What do tx_hash,tx_hash_big_endian,tx_index,tx_output_n and value stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tx_hash` and `tx_hash_big_endian` are the transaction id of the transaction that this output originated from in little endian and big endian (reversed).

`tx_output_n` is the number of the output in the referenced transaction, i.e if a transaction has 5 outputs and you need to refer to the 5th you use a `tx_output_n` = 5.

`tx_index` I believe is an internal unique key that blockchain.info uses to identify transactions

`script` is the ScriptPubKey of the output, that is the conditions you need to fullfill to be able to redeem the coins.

Comment: I imagine that in building transactions we need to use `tx_hash` and not the big endian? I wish they would document stuff

Answer (score 2):

> **I guess that the script is the owner's address.I am not sure about this.**

According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

> Bitcoin uses a scripting system for transactions. Forth-like, Script is simple, stack-based, and processed from left to right. It is intentionally not Turing-complete, with no loops.
>
> A script is essentially a list of instructions recorded with each transaction that describe how the next person wanting to spend the Bitcoins being transferred can gain access to them.

In your example

| Hex | script operation | Effect |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x76 | OP_DUP | Duplicates the top stack item |
| 0xa9 | OP_HASH160 | Hashes top stack item with SHA-256 then with RIPEMD-160. |
| 7f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a8 | data | - |
| 0x88 | OP_EQUALVERIFY | Compares top two stack items |
| 0xac | OP_CHECKSIG | Computes transaction hash and verifies signature |

See [Bitcoin script example](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2251/13866)

The above is a [standard script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Standard_Transaction_to_Bitcoin_address_.28pay-to-pubkey-hash.29) which requires the spender to prove that they own the destination address of an unspent transaction output. The data in it is a hash of a public-key. Inputs prepended to the script are a signature and public key